# Kotlin- Primary and Secondary Constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

```
class SmartDevice(val name: String, val category: String) {
    var deviceStatus = "online"

    constructor(name: String, category: String, statusCode: Int) : this(name, category) {
        deviceStatus = when (statusCode) {
            0 -> "offline"
            1 -> "online"
            else -> "unknown"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

can some one explain me the flow of execution of this program, in kotlin??

Answer (score 1):

When the primary constructor is called:

1. The backing fields of the `name` and `category` properties are initialized with the parameters passed to the constructor.
2. The backing field of the `deviceStatus` property is initialized with `"online"`.

When the secondary constructor is called:

1. The primary constructor is called and passed along the `name` and `category` parameters that were passed to the secondary constructor. So all the above steps occur.
2. The setter of the `deviceStatus` property is called and passed the result of the `when` expression. The default setter for the `var` will reassign the backing field’s value.

Answer (score 0):

The primary constructor will be called first in your code:

```
class SmartDevice(val name: String, val category: String) {
    var deviceStatus = "online"
     
     init {
         // This is your primary constructor's body. 
         // This will be called 1st.
         // Do something here with. `name` and `category` properties are initialized
     }

    constructor(name: String, category: String, statusCode: Int) : this(name, category) {
        deviceStatus = when (statusCode) {
            0 -> "offline"
            1 -> "online"
            else -> "unknown"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

If you want to do some execution of code in your primary constructor, you need to add init block in the class. If you do not add, it is by default empty.

Comment: All the properties with initializers are part of the constructor’s execution, from top to bottom, and there can be multiple `init` blocks mixed in among initialized properties.

Answer (score 0):

This code will execute in the following steps:

1. When an instance of SmartDevice is created using the primary constructor, it sets the name and category properties, and the deviceStatus is initialized to "online" by default.

Ex: `val device = SmartDevice("DeviceName", "CategoryName")`

2. If an instance of SmartDevice is created using the secondary constructor with a statusCode, it will set the deviceStatus based on the provided code.

Ex: `val device1 = SmartDevice("OfflineDevice", "CategoryType", 0)`

In this case, offlineDevice.deviceStatus will be set to "offline" because the statusCode is 0.

Ex: `val device2 = SmartDevice("UnknownDevice", "CategoryType", 2)`

In this case, unknownDevice.deviceStatus will be set to "unknown" because the statusCode is neither 0 nor 1.

So, depending on how you create an instance of SmartDevice, the deviceStatus property will be initialized accordingly. If you don't provide a statusCode, the default value of "online" will be used.